# How to add additional JUnit Tests for a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I know how to set up up JUnit tests for a class. For a class I want to test on, I just right click the class name -> new JUnit Test Case and eventually was met with 
[image]

Is there a way to get to this dialog if you want to add add test cases for additional methods to your current Junit class? I don't want to create a completely new Junit class for testing nor do i want to manually write out every test method stub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to get to this dialog if you want to add add test cases
>   for additional methods to your current Junit class?

Yes, just run the wizard in the same exact way you did for the class that already has unit tests. Make another test class and then move the new methods over to the existing test and delete the redundant test class.

1. Right-click the class to be tested > New > Other...
2. Java > JUnit > JUnit Test Case
3. Enter a temporary test class name and package, click Next
4. Select additional methods to test, click Finish
5. Cut the new test methods out of the temp test case and paste into existing one
6. Delete temp test class

Answer (score 0):

you can add as many test case you want using the `@org.junit.Test` annotation.

if you have more than one test classes you can combine them into suit using the
`@Suite.SuiteClasses` and the `@RunWith` annotation.

Have a look here: [Unit Testing with JUnit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)